# Laravel : Ignore object in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a question concerning best practise with Laravel. I have a blade page who display all my products and I test if my product has image in my loop, I ignore it if it's the case :

```
       @foreach ($products as $product)
            @if(is_null($product->getMedia()->first())) 
                @continue
            @endif 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 //display image and product informations
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

My question is :
Is this correct ?

Or souhld I ignore the product who has no image in my controller ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you please share your product model as well?

Comment: better doing the logic in php, and sending the final output to blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you consider products without any images to be "invalid" / "inactive", or if you just don't want to show them in this particular view.

Your controller is defining a business requirement like "fetch all products which match certain conditions". If "has an image" is part of that business requirement, because any product without an image should not be on sale, then the logic goes in your controller.

Your view is defining a particular presentation like "arrange the products in a pretty grid". If "has an image" is just a requirement to work in this layout, skipping here could be reasonable.

However, completely skipping products in the view may have some undesirable consequences:

- If these products *should* be on sale, as implied by the controller returning them, hiding them means customers can't see them.
- If you have pagination, or a total number of results found, it won't match the number of products the user can actually see unless you take care to handle the skipped products.

It's therefore most appropriate if you are building some kind of "highlights", where the skipped products will actually be shown in a list further down, just not as prominently.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your media. if it is the same table with your product, it is ok, but if it is a relation, it is better to filter it in your controller.

Comment: This answer my question. Thanks.
Obvious, do the logic in controller. Think I'm tired today